# Aptana Studio 3.0.7 - CSS autocomplete only from the 2. line

Tags: css, autocomplete, aptana

i get CSS autocomplete only from the second line. There's no autocomplete at the first line? 
And sometimes i get absolutely no autocomplete...
What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for reading that!

Answer (score 7):

I guess they changed some settings, because it used to work instantly in previous Aptana versions. Here is what helped me with this problem in Aptana 3:

Window > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Content Assist > **Auto-Display content assist**

Change this drop-down from Default delay to **Instant**. Press Apply and Ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't mind if you've already tried this and seems trivial. It wasn't for me!

Having moved from Dreamweaver where autocomplete comes on its own, I struggled with Aptana autocomplete at first. Sometimes in Aptana 3.0.7, it doesn't show up on its own and we need to hit Ctrl + Enter (on Windows)!

Also try Ctrl + Enter after typing at leaset 1- 3 Chars. This can be changed in Settings.

Hope this helps...